# How to pass command and argument to a container in deployment file of kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have to write a deployment file for my application which takes run time commands and arguments at runtime.
e.g. `./foo bar -a=A -b=B`
This is my deployment file :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: foo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: foo
        image: username/image:tag
        # command that to be executed at run time
        command: ["bar"]
        args:
        # This is the flag to pass at runtime
        - -a=A
        - -b=B
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9500
```

It says container command 'foo' not found or doesnot exist.
i'm passing a script as entrypoint and it has `exec  /usr/local/bin/foo` .
What's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want start `./foo bar -a=A -b=B` in container, your deployment should contains

```
- name: foo
  image: username/image:tag
  command: ["foo"]
  args: ["bar", "-a=A", "-b=B"]
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Be sure you have path to **foo** binary in your **$PATH** enviroment variable inside `username/image:tag` image (or use full path `/usr/local/bin/foo`).

You can check `$PATH` by

```
kubectl run  test -ti --rm --image=username/image:tag --command -- echo $PATH

kubectl run  test -ti --rm --image=username/image:tag --command -- foo
```

Comment: thanks @delfer, i got my mistake, i was giving my binary as ENTRYPOINT rather than as CMD. So i changed ENTRYPOINT to CMD and it worked.....

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
- name: foo
  image: username/image:tag
  command: 
    - bar
    - '-a=A'
    - '-b=B'
```